# How to change the field type of result set from SQL pass-through (SPT)?

Tags: mysql, sql, visual-foxpro, pass-through

I have a mysql table column defined as `unit_price float(12,4)`.

If I assign a value of `0.1234`, when I create a remote view with `dbsetprop`, I can retrieve `0.1234` with `myview.unit_price`.

However, when I use SQL pass-through (SPT) like this:

```
sqlexec(nHandle, "select * from table", "oResult")
```

the result of `oResult.unit_price` only shows `0.12`.

How can I ensure that I return the correct, full value?

Answer (score 0):

Not having explicitly tried, you can do some simple math forcing to create larger precision, such as adding an additional column to your query... something like...

```
select *, unit_price * 1.00000 as UnitPrice5 from...
```

This will force the field to be computed to 5 decimal position and MIGHT actually change the result column to properly handle this forced decimal capacity.  Then, you would use the "UnitPrice5" column instead of "unit_price"...

Don't know if that would be a big issue for you, but once it is in VFP, you have more control too.

Comment: i have tried your method, still cannot, but thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

The length of the decimal values are defined in your FoxPro settings.  Go to Tools->Options->Regional and set the Decimal Digits to a higher value.